# Grails4 getting out of memory while compiling groovy

Tags: groovy, compilation, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, grails-4

I am getting below out of memory error in my grails4 application after adding more controllers in my workspace.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':cira:compileGroovy'.

  > GC overhead limit exceeded

so far i have total of 41 controller files in my grails application while adding 42 one i am getting this error while compiling if i remove it and run with existing 41 controllers its working.

Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How much RAM do you have free on your devbox? Or how do you build?

Comment: It is 16gb ram laptop i am building app using gradle

Comment: What java memory (and gc) parameters are you using?  Also does it matter which controller you remove?  (Wondering if it's any 42nd controller, or something going wrong in the one you just added specifically.)

Comment: ITs any 42nd controller not with any particular controller. Regarding java memory i am running on jdk 1.8 64 bit i tried adding below in buid.gradle bootRun {
    jvmArgs(
        '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always', 
        '-noverify', 
        '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
  '-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=N')           Please let me know if you want me to try passing specific memory parameters in build.gradle or gradle.properties

Answer (score 0):

Modify bootRun block of build.gradle as follows

```
bootRun {
ignoreExitValue true
jvmArgs(
    '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always',
    '-noverify',
    '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
    '-Xmx4096m')
sourceResources sourceSets.main
String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
systemProperty springProfilesActive, 
System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}
```